# Automatic updates for NAT instances and SSH connections in a AWS VPC with private subnets

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, nat, upgrade

My current website architecture has two Ubuntu servers with public IPs in Rackspace Cloud. One of them is web and mysql server. The other one is for  time-consuming calculations only. Both of them have Iptables which allow all outbound traffic and inbound HTTP, HTTPS, SSH and established connections. I connect to the servers with ssh using password, but this connection is protected with Fail2ban. I use unattended upgrades to keep the servers updated.

I'm moving to **Amazon AWS** and considering to change my current architecture to use a **VPC with Public and Private Subnets**. However, I have some doubts:

- I would use a **default (small) nat instance. I assume that it needs to keep updated, does it update automatically?**
- I would have three other instances: a web server in the public subnet and a mysql server and a computation server in the private subnet. **How do I access each of these instances with ssh?**
- Is this architecture more secure than my current one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

- No the instance does not auto-update you need to configure that (Amazon Linux is very much like CentOS - you will find instructions for that)
- You use an instance which is reachable from the internet and hop to the instances in the private VPC from this one (gateway)
- You just need to make sure your ACL and security groups are set correctly and monitor the internet-faced instances. The advantage of such an architecture (private subnets) is the fact of fewer instances which are internet-faced (which leads to a smaller point of attack.